# Javascript - Load a page 4 times then change on the 5th time

Tags: javascript

I'm making a rolling screen based in PHP, i use javascript to load a page every 10 seconds. Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>   
 setInterval(function(){
      $('#container').fadeOut('slow').load('screener.php').fadeIn("slow");
     },10000);
</script>
```

so i'm guessing I need a count to load either screener.php or if the count = 5, load alternate.php.

Comment: So... What's the question? Can you explain more about what are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what you need to do.

```
var counter = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    if (counter % 5 === 0) {
        $('#container').fadeOut('slow').load('alternate.php').fadeIn("slow");
    } else {
        $('#container').fadeOut('slow').load('screener.php').fadeIn("slow");
    }

    counter++;
 },10000);
```